# Migrating from VisualAge for Java to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, visual-age

Currently, we are using IBM VisualAge for Java to program Swing classes for our legacy system. We plan on migrating to Eclipse, but I cannot find a simple way how to. Is there any tool to migrate the VisualAge Java classes repository (.dat file) and visual composition of Swing classes to Eclipse?

Comment: Holy s*** somebody still using that.

Comment: Are you talking about the UI Designer generated stuff?

Comment: @RomainHippeau Yes, sadly. That's why we need help to migrate to eclipse.

Comment: @chenyi1976 In VisualAge, we can view the Swing design. I just need a migration tool that will enable eclipse to view the Swing design just as the way VisualAge does. Thanks.

Comment: @Arci I never tried VisualAge, but I used UI designer in JBuilder, now I switch IntelliJ IDEA, so same problem happens to me too. I do not think there is a solution for this kind issue. Now I have abandon the UI designer tools, code the UI manually now, it is a bit painful, but you gain full control to everything no matter what tool generate those UI code.

Comment: @chenyi1976 I'll wait for more reply. I still have lot of hopes since it's made by IBM, so there should be at least a tool to migrate to Eclipse. Anyway, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse includes the WindowBuilder tool that is pretty good at reading existing UI code and providing a nice "visual" edit mode for it. The latest **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** package includes WindowBuilder; it can also be installed into any of the other packages via **Help > Install New Software**.

You can learn all about WindowBuilder at http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

Comment: That is good but the problem is, we have around thousands of java classes and the first thing we should do is migrate the repository(.dat file) to Eclipse format repository. Then, as I have said before, we need to view its "visual composition" using eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use a repository, Visual Age was unique that way. Now, everything is stored as files on the file system instead of as records in a VAJ repository. It's been years since I used VAJ, but I'm pretty sure there is some kind of export feature that will give you the .java and/or .class files. Then you can import that into a new Eclipse project.